# How would a girl that has never encountered the concept of pregnancy react to giving birth? This one seems on topic, but unpopular for obvious reasons

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close

[How would a girl that has never encountered the concept of pregnancy react to giving birth?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/82574/how-would-a-girl-that-has-never-encountered-the-concept-of-pregnancy-react-to-gi)

This question seems appropriately scoped and reasonably on-topic as far as worldbuilding goes, but it appears to be gathering closevotes for being off-topic.

Admittedly the question could use some perspective, but is it really off-topic or is this a [super down vote issue](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4927/flags-and-close-votes-are-not-super-downvotes)?

Comment: __Comments removed.__ Remember to [be nice](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in the question, I suspect that this question was closed more because people disliked the premise and/or subject matter... More or less a case of "I dislike this so much I'll downvote and vote to close"

And it was pretty easy for them to justify closing it as too story based, due to the original wording.

Honestly my thought was that the premise was fabricated​ just to ask a question about maternal instincts... The whole "baby females" thing seemed underdeveloped. How did they survive to maturity without observing some basic things about procreation in the natural world around them? But that seemed more or less immaterial to the question, just a reason that these women didn't know anything about pregnancy or birth etc. But that's a pretty huge handwave, and many users were probably skeptical about it.

Beyond that I suspect that some users were probably unsettled about the subject matter. Anytime you're talking about sex, gender and/or procreation some people are going to get a little more sensitive. I'm sure that it wasn't your intention to stir those sensitivities, but it's good to be aware of how people may be reading into your motives.

When you say things like:
"What might this uninformed female think of that weird stuff that just crept out of her"

It sets a certain tone... It gives people who are already feeling a little suspicious about your personal motives for asking about a charged subject more of a reason to feel suspicious. Your question and your story touch on some hot button issues. I'm certainly not trying to tell you not to talk about hot button issues, just be aware of how you do it and be aware of how people may react.

Comment: @wetcircuit it's better to post your point of view in an answer. Comments are temporary and may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

My question was previously about motherhood psychology, however some people got stuck in trying to make it sexual, somehow, and in the premises.

Admittedly, the question as it was posed was badly formulated, and could've done better just by asking the thing I wanted to know right away. My fault for not properly assessing the level of abstraction users expect to read in these forums.

So yeah, the answer to your question, as I see it, is that after having researched quite a bit trying to discover what had closed my question down is that it was not entirely obvious to the other members of the community what the question was about, and the question they tried to substitute to answer, another psychological concept called "attribute substitution", when striving to know wheter they should focus on the premise or the actual question was "can I imagine what people I know would do in that situation?", for which the answer is obviously "no", because they can't PERSONALLY relate to that, instead of "Is there a scientific or psychological concept or experiment I know of that would explain behaviour in a state not found in a classical situation that would help analyse this case?", which is a question that is a lot harder to answer. Then, as the answer was obviously "no", to the question they ended up unadvertedly answering, the question seemed stupid and the whole thing seemed out of scope.

Comment: Thank you for coming to meta to discuss the question.  I'm sorry you got a less than wonderful welcome; I've removed several comments that were on the wrong side of our "be nice" policy.

Comment: There *are* psychological experiments that address the case, namely Harry Harlow's monkey experiments, and also human situations such as the Romanian orphanages. The "subjects" raised without adult human care would likely have severe emotional and developmental problems.

Comment: @wetcircuit if you could flesh that out, it could make a reasonable answer to the original post, but there isn't much point in continuing to push the issue in comments.

Comment: @apaul34208 I did, but as the OP stated that wasn't the actual question

Comment: I feel like that this answer of yours might make sense in the original question, because the WAY I had stated the question, which I wrongly assumed wouldn't matter, and would only be used for context, however, the question as now stated, which is what I wanted to know since the beggining, doesn't lend itself well to that view, since the question doesn't touch on the conditions that lead to the state I wanted to analyse psychologically. Nonetheless, do feel encouraged to post an answer there, if you feel like it.